# Highchart set data value from array 2 dimension in function paramater Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts

Hallo its my first time to use highcharts & laravel 6, i want to make value data from database, in array 2 dimension.

first i make function for convert datetime to timestamp

```
function convertTime(date)
{
    var year = date.split("-")[0],
    month = date.split("-")[1],
    second_part = date.split("-")[2],
    day = second_part.split(" ")[0],
    last_part2 = second_part.split(" ")[1],
    hour = last_part2.split(":")[0],
    minute =  last_part2.split(":")[1],
    second =  last_part2.split(":")[2];

    var d = new Date (Date.UTC(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second ));

    return d.getTime();
}
```

heres the code script code in view blade

```
$(function () {
    $('#chartschedule').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            min: Date.UTC(2019,9,25),
            max: Date.UTC(2019,9,26),
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Schedule'
            },
            categories: {!!json_encode($schedule)!!},
            reversed: true
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            "marker": {
                "enabled": true,
                "symbol": "diamond"
            },
            data: [
                foreach
                [converterTime({!!json_encode($point_time)!!}),{!!json_encode($point_data)!!}]

            ],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 10, 25),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
       }]

    });
});
```

i want try data value like what i do in categories
`data: [converterTime({!!json_encode($point_time)!!}),{!!json_encode($point_data)!!}]`

contents of data array:

-schedule
[studiying, training, playing]

-point_time
[2019-28-10 13:00:00, 2019-28-10 14:00:00, 2019-28-10 15:00:00]

-point_data
[0, 1, 2]

but chart still not showing, i'm still didnt get it why ?, can anyone explain it ?
im use this link for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/93Xcu/7/

thankyou

Comment: Hi @Raka Aditya, Any errors in the console? I have tried to reproduce your problem. Could you confirm that this is the result you get? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wbz4ue53/

Comment: sorry for late reply @ppotaczek, yes the result is graph is not showing, but in your case you didnt convert the datetime to timestamp (this problem solved already), thats why i make convert the data from datetime to timestamp. What i mean is more like the value of the data is not showing, although i have did like in categories. The data is from controller, it is not statistic, i try to make it dynamic 
because it takes data from the database.

Comment: Hi @Raka Aditya, The source of the data is not important. If the data is in the format required by Highcharts, the chart will work. Could you reproduce your problem in jsfiddle by using static data?